# Changeable background for <div> section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to write html where one section is like this:

```
<div id="...." style="background-image:url(---.jpg);">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I am thinking of creating an image folder in the host-directory and give user option to select an appropriate image which can act as a background for the above . Can somebody suggest me, how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Yes, I do but I don't know how I can use it to accomplish the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not as simple as you think

If you do not want to care about which images are available in the folder, you will need a server process that can return the content of that folder as a list, for example given

```
<div id="someDiv">Some content to make sure the div is not collapsed</div>
```

you need to generate something like this (inline is not recommended, using jQuery or similar would simplify your code)

```
<a href="someimage.jpg" 
onclick="document.getElementById('someDiv').style.backgroundImage=this.href;
return false"><img src="someimage.jpg" height="100" /></a>
```

---

To use autocomplete you could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#autocomplete").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 ) {
      $('#someDiv').("background-image", "url("+$(this).val()+")");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source: ["apple.jpg", "banana.jpg","orange"]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the images to the user.
And then using jQuery, you add a function to the click event of the images.
This function would then set the div's background to the apropriate image.

```
<img src="..." class="bg_image" />
<img src="..." class="bg_image" />
<img src="..." class="bg_image" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.bg_image').click(function(){
    $('#the_div').css('background-image', $(this).css('backgound-image'));
});
</script>
```

Read this as a sudo-code to get the idea how you should do it. I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the style property like this:

```
document.getElementById("....").style.backgroundImage = 'url(whatever.jpg)';
```

Comment: That was all I needed! works great for my purpose...Thanks a lot

Comment: That was all I needed! works great for my purpose. One question though, how can I make background image accept the output from jquery's AUTOCOMPLETE feature and use it to choose the desired image?

Comment: first, you're welcome. Consider upvoting answers you find useful btw.

Comment: then, I don't know the Autocomplete feature, I think's it's part of jQuery UI. but I think it would be smthing like this: autocomplete = $('#input').autocomplete({...}).onChange( function(){ $(bg).css('background-image','url('+$(this).val()+')') } );

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="target" ></div>

var div = document.getElementById('target');
div.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/intro.gif')";
```

for path form a variable

```
var path = "pics/intro.gif";
div.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + path + "')";
```

Or using jQuery

```
$("#target").css("background-image", "url('" + path + "')");
```

Comment: Are you sure that notation works? I would expect backgroundImage